Mesh subdivide + split by loose geometry
Sounds so simple but I can't get it to work. I want to create a cube, subdivide, then split by loose geometry so that the small subdivided cubes which comprise the original cube, become independent cube meshes.
Cheers

How did you actually try to split the cube? By using Subdivide in Edit Mode? That splits the surface in the sense of subdividing the larger faces into smaller faces, but they are not separate or loose geometry. A subdivided face is just more faces connected by their mutual edges. And especially they are not small cubes, even if those faces were separated, that would make them planes. Subdividing the surface does not automatically create geometry on the inside of the cube which would be needed to get smaller cubes.

Sure I understand the premise of subdividing faces. But how do you subdivide a mesh into multiple meshes?

Simple answer is that it's not possible because, as @GordonBrinkmann says, simply subdividing doesn't produce internal geometry to create the faces. It might be possible to create them using Geometry Nodes but that's outside my experience.

When you have a subdivided cube and everything selected, you can go to the menu Mesh and choose Split > Faces by Edges_ and now all faces are separated.

If you only have some faces selected, these will become separate individual faces. Choosing Split > Selection or the shortcut Y will separate the selected faces from the unselected faces as well, but connected face selections will stay connected by their mutual edges.
The complete Split menu you can also bring up as context menu in the viewport with the shortcut Alt+M.
But as mentioned in my comment, this does not produce small cubes. For that you would need something like Geometry Nodes, but actually there you can simply use grids etc. to tell Blender where the smaller cubes should be, similar like you could arrange small cubes with an Array modifier to build a larger cube, but for these methods there is no need to subdivide a cube beforehand.

Hi Gordon, this method splits the faces yes, but does not create separate cube meshes. If I do your method, then p - by loose parts, then go back to object mode, the only thing I can select is individual faces, not cube meshes. Do you see what I am saying?

@EHB Yes, and I already told you in the comments that this is not possible with subdividing a mesh. In the comment you then just said you would know that and only mentioned a mesh into multiple meshes... which doesn't necessarily mean cubes ;) I added a bit at the end of the answer: you can get small cubes to build a large cube with the Array modifier or Geometry Nodes - but these methods would not require a subdivided mesh or actually a subdivided mesh might make it even more complicated than doing it differently.

@EHB The problem with this, these are no real world objects. A cube is defined by its surfaces. It is not a solid object filled with matter through and through, you cannot cut it with a knife like a block of cheese. Sure, the Boolean modifier creates faces inside a geometry, but they are where the faces of the cutter object were. Creating a cutter object which would result in a collection of small cubes building a large cube without any glitches is more tedious than simply stacking small cubes on top of each other.
